# C# Alternative to Model Maker Code Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've changed from delphi to c#/visual studio and I see [model maker code explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer-vs/screenshots.html#overview) (one of my favourite tools) is available for visual studio ... question is are there any better alternatives?

I've had a play around with resharper and it's good some good refactoring/code highlighting features ... but one thing I really like about code explorer was the way you could view the classes and functions so easily on the side. Just makes life so much easier. Visual studios class explorer kind of helps but you always have to navigate to the class rather than it showing the classes of the unit you're currently viewing. So any visual studio tools that do a good job of this? or should I just stick with model maker code explorer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Code Explorer. Do you have any examples of what it looks like to help think of similar tools for VS?

Comment: Seems I fogot to add the link to their site http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer-vs/screenshots.html#overview

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the SKU of Visual Studio that you have (ie: not Express), the built-in *Code Definition Window* might be useful. It's a read-only code window that shows you the declaration of whatever element your cursor is upon.

I only recently discovered the Code Definition Window and have found it quite useful - the [original blog entry](http://www.chrisbrandsma.com/2007/03/visual-studionet-tool-i-didnt-know.html) I saw was by Chris Brandsma.

Comment: perhaps not exactly what I was after but looks like it could be pretty handy sometimes

Answer (score 1):

There's two set of enhancements I use a lot for Visual Studio (being a Delphi-convert myself):

- [PowerCommands v1.1 for VisualStudio 2008](http://www.visualstudiogallery.com/ExtensionDetails.aspx?ExtensionID=df3f0c30-3d37-4e06-9ef8-3bff3508be31) adds lots of interesting and helpful bells'n'whistles, mostly to the Solution Explorer
- Visual Studio 2008 [SourceCode Outliner PowerToy](http://www.codeplex.com/SourceCodeOutliner/)

Both are free, behave well, and are indispensable IMHO :-)

Comment: Thanks for that, the source code outliner does what I was wanting ... and the price is right!